# Can an object set it self to null?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, is it possible for an object to do suicide, that is set it self to null ?

this=null; didn't work....

The reason for wanting such ting is that if e.g. the object gets data in via constructor that is not good (for any reason), then it might be better off being null than rubbish.

A status flag is a workaround, but that is my second best alternative.

Comment: can you explain this part: *the object gets data in via constructor that is not good*

Comment: don't immediately know if you could do this, but i know you should not WANT to do this, that is what exceptions are for.
Also, an object not being there at all is better than the object being null if it was "rubbish"

Comment: You can dispose youself with Dispose()

Comment: The question is why do you want do it ? 
Is it to test the object in a second time  ?

Comment: So, after you call the constructor `var agenda = new Suicide()`, you're probably going to check if it's null, right? `if (agenda == null)`. Tell me: What's the difference between writing that or using a status flag: `if (agenda.Status == Status.DeadMeat)`. I'm failing to see why you want to assign null.

Comment: @TimothyGroote The object setting itself to null during construction is the pattern used in Objective-C, but that language treats null objects differently to C# (note that that was a very simplistic description)

Comment: @PeterM thanks for that, that gives me some insight in why someone would ask this question in the first place :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No the object cannot set itself into null, it's the reference that can be set to null.

Just throw an `ArgumentException` insteed

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you throw an `ArgumentException` from the constructor in case you receive problematic data from the caller. Then catch that in the calling code.

Comment: I would argue that `ArgumentException` should pretty much never be caught: it should usually indicate a bug in the calling code. It *may* still be an appropriate exception to use, or possibly a different exception if the caller couldn't know that the argument was inappropriate (e.g. it's a filename and it fails to read from that file). Either way, an exception is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

If the object needs external data in order to complete its construction and gets something unusable (or no data at all) then what you need to do is throw an appropriate exception.

Changing the value of `this` is illegal, and even if it were not it would not offer any benefit: the caller still has to determine what happened during construction.

Answer (score 3):

You should throw an exception in the constructor; this will prevent the object from being created all together:

```
 class MyClass {
       public MyClass(string value) {
           if (value == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
           ... 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can play with `this` how you want.

In C# - only in restricted way. For example, you can assign `struct`'s, but not the `class`' this to something